# Instance variable in other controller - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a mostly static website built with Rails. Each page is managed by a pages controller. I have a contact form at the bottom of each page. I am using mail_form. Each form requires a new ContactForm object. I have defined contact form. This is it's schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170130205713) do

create_table "contact_forms", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "message"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

end
```

Here is the controller:

```
class ContactFormsController < ApplicationController
def new
  @contact_form = ContactForm.new
end

def create
  begin
    @contact_form = ContactForm.new(params[:contact_form])
    @contact_form.request = request
    if @contact_form.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
    else
      render :new
    end
  rescue ScriptError
    flash[:error] = 'Sorry, this message appears to be spam and was not delivered.'
  end
end
end
```

I would like to be able to create a new instance of the ContactForm object in each of the page controller's views. When I attempt to define

```
@contact_form = ContactForm.new
```

in the home view of the pages controller, for example, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in PagesController#home
undefined method `type' for {:validate=>true}:Hash
```

Is there a way to do this without moving all of my actions into the ContactForm controller?

Comment: The error is in `PagesController` but you only showed us `ContactFormsController`...

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly, you need to have an instance variable of contact_form that could be used in every page as every page has contact form in its bottom.

You could create a private method in ApplicationController and use that as 'before_action' in whatever controller, whose action you need that object to be present. Something like below

Add below line in ApplicationController.rb

```
private
def init_contact_form
  @contact_form ||= ContactForm.new
end
```

And use below in Controller where you need that @contact_form object.
Add below in your PagesController.rb

```
before_action :init_contact_form
```